# Creating a Resume Header

Tags: cv

I would like to recreate this résumé header in LaTeX. I'm having quite a bit of trouble with it. I'm a bit of a LaTeX novice.

Resume Header:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEgS5.png]

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

The `memoir` class provides a good method of creating a custom header with three parts. As set up here, the header will appear on every page as a custom letterhead. The technique is explained in the comments below.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, oneside]{memoir}

    % Select a font package here (any TeX engine), or use fontspec with LuaLaTex or XeLaTeX
    % If it has to look like Times New Roman, \usepackage{tgtermes} instead 
    \usepackage{lmodern} 

    % Set dimensions of text block for memoir
    % For example, 1-inch margins on letter-size paper, with extra on top for header
    \settypeblocksize{9in}{6.5in}{*}
    \setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
    \setulmarginsandblock{1.5in}{1in}{*}
    % Set header and footer size
    \setheadfoot{4\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
    \checkandfixthelayout

    % Create a custom header for every page:
    % The three parameters of \makeoddhead{headers} define the left, center, and right parts of the header.
    % We use macros for the data and then fill them in below.
    % Use any formating commands within each bracketed parameter.
    \copypagestyle{headers}{plain}
    \makeoddhead{headers}
        %left side
        {\currentAddress}
        % center
        {{\Large\bfseries\name}\\ \vspace{0.5em} {\footnotesize\email \\ \phone }}
        % right side
        {\permanentAddress}
    % A horizontal rule beneath the header looks nice
    \makeheadrule{headers}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
    % Activate your custom header
    \pagestyle{headers}

    % Now supply the information to be put into the header above: This makes it easier to change
    \newcommand{\name}{LaTeX User}
    \newcommand{\currentAddress}{123 Main St.\\ Current City, State 12345}
    \newcommand{\permanentAddress}{321 Main St.\\ Permanent City, State 54321}
    \newcommand{\email}{mwe@example.com}
    \newcommand{\phone}{(123) 456-7890}

    \begin{document}
    %********************

    % Here is one basic way to format CV information 
    \section*{Information}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item{Fact 1}
        \item{Fact 2}
    \end{itemize}

    %*******************
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I make this for only the first page?

Comment: In the preamble, omit the line `\pagestyle{headers}` so that the default pagestyle remains `plain`. Then, just after `\begin{document}`, write `\thispagestyle{headers}`, and TeX will only apply your custom style to the first page.

Comment: I'm also having trouble with the margins. I want to use letter size paper and 0.5 in margins all around. When I try to change \setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*} and \setulmarginsandblock{1.5in}{1in}{*} to 0.5 I get errors

Answer (score 1):

You could start with something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\Email[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXr}
  \textbf{Current address} &\Large Your name & \textbf{Permanent address} \\
  ... & Email address: \Email{my.email.address@somewhere} &
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

A few possibly obvious points that may be worth highlighting since you are just starting out:

- the `\textwidth` argument to the `tabularx` environment says that the width of the table is the page width.
- the easiest way to specify the margins etc is with the [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry)
- you can add hyperlinks to the pdf file using the [hyperref packagae](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: `\noindent` before the `tabularx`; otherwise, an overfull box will be produced.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Good point. Fixed.